# PHP array sorting anomaly

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm having trouble sorting an array in PHP and I'm having some trouble with the basic sort() routine.

For example,

```
$arr = array("J1", "N1", "J10", "J2");
```

When using the sort routine, my output is:
J1, J10, J2, N1.

My desired output is:
J1, **J2, J10,** N1.

Does anyone know a more suited sorting algorithm for this type of problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Because `'J10' < 'J2'`. The character `1` goes before `2` in characters table.

Comment: I know why it's sorting them in that way, I'm just curious if there is a way to sort these by alphabetical and then numeric from the first character after. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) function.

```
$arr = array("J1", "N1", "J10", "J2");
natsort($arr);

var_dump($arr);

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "J1"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "J2"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "J10"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "N1"
}
```